# ruby on rails question: intercept and buffer params to use after an intermediate action returned successful (via ajax)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am looking for the best way how to intercept a request with params from a user. store the params away and use them only if an intermediate action returns successfully.

it`s kinda a multistep form. but the intermediate form data has nothing to do with the other form`s model.

so it should be like a dynamic request interception. all requests are made via ajax btw..

thanks for any hints or help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd tuck it away in the session if it's a small amount of form data (not a huge text entry or file upload)